# Persistence Message send on Virtual Destination persistence Store

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, middleware

How acknowledgment and persistence works with virtual destination?

If I have a Virtual Topic "VirtualTopic.A" and two consumers
1. Queue on this virtual topic "Consumer.B.VirtualTopic.A",
2. A durable consumer subscribed to this VirtualTopic

then all persistent messages sent on VirtualTopic.A will get stored for Queue "Consumer.B.VirtualTopic.A" as well.

Why is this happening, is there a way to disable this?

Is there a way to disable this when all consumer subscribed to that queue have un-subscribed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately not.

The point of a virtual topic is exactly the behavior you are describing.  It is a way to allow pub/sub like behavior, but allow for the persistence of a queue.  Basically any queue that matches your virtual topic definition sort of becomes a subscriber to the topic in that definition.  As with a normal queue with a producer, there is no requirement for a consumer to be consuming for a messaged to be produced to that queue.

If you don't care about missing messages while a consumer is down, then you should go with normal subscribers to a topic, rather than consumers consuming from a virtual topic queue.